# Bazel Android Hello World Tutorial: Error Building

Tags: bazel

Edit: Original problem fixed. Replaced bazel.exe file with file downloaded from [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/6.0.0-pre.20220608.2). Now I'm getting the below error message. Any ideas?

> C:\Users\scott\examples\android\tutorial>bazel build //src/main:app
> --features=compiler_param_file --verbose_failures
>
> Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it... INFO: Analyzed
> target //src/main:app (55 packages loaded, 1052 targets configured).
> INFO: Found 1 target... ERROR:
> C:/users/scott/examples/android/tutorial/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/BUILD:7:16:
> Desugaring src/main/java/com/example/bazel/libgreeter_activity.jar for
> Android failed: Worker process did not return a WorkResponse:
>
> ---8<---8<--- Start of log, file at C:/tmp/6jyys53n/bazel-workers/worker-5-Desugar.log ---8<---8<--- grep:
> C:\tmp\6jyys53n\execroot_*main*_\bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\bazel_tools\tools\android\desugar_java8.runfiles/MANIFEST:
> No such file or directory
> C:\tmp\6jyys53n\execroot_*main*_\bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\bazel_tools\tools\android\desugar_java8:
> line 114: : command not found
> ---8<---8<--- End of log ---8<---8<--- Target //src/main:app failed to build INFO: Elapsed time: 18.032s, Critical Path: 9.29s INFO: 49
> processes: 28 internal, 13 local, 8 worker. FAILED: Build did NOT
> complete successfully

**ORIGINAL POST BELOW - RESOLVED**

I'm getting an error building the bazel Hello World tutorial project outlined [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/tutorial/android-app.html). I used two different build tools versions from Android SDK and got different errors:

WORKSPACE FILE:
android_sdk_repository(
name = "androidsdk",
build_tools_version = "30.0.3"
)

> C:\Users\scott\examples\android\tutorial>bazel build //src/main:app
> --features=compiler_param_file --verbose_failures
>
> INFO: Analyzed target //src/main:app (26 packages loaded, 649 targets
> configured). INFO: Found 1 target... ERROR:
> C:/users/scott/examples/android/tutorial/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/BUILD:7:16:
> Desugaring src/main/java/com/example/bazel/libgreeter_activity.jar for
> Android failed: Worker process did not return a WorkResponse:
>
> ---8<---8<--- Start of log, file at C:/tmp/6jyys53n/bazel-workers/worker-8-Desugar.log ---8<---8<--- grep:
> C:\tmp\6jyys53n\execroot_*main*_\bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\bazel_tools\tools\android\desugar_java8.runfiles/MANIFEST:
> No such file or directory
> C:\tmp\6jyys53n\execroot_*main*_\bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\bazel_tools\tools\android\desugar_java8:
> line 114: : command not found
> ---8<---8<--- End of log ---8<---8<--- Target //src/main:app failed to build INFO: Elapsed time: 1.587s, Critical Path: 0.66s INFO: 3
> processes: 3 internal. FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

WORKSPACE FILE:
android_sdk_repository(
name = "androidsdk",
build_tools_version = "33.0.0"
)

> C:\Users\scott\examples\android\tutorial>bazel build //src/main:app
> --features=compiler_param_file --verbose_failures
>
> INFO: Analyzed target //src/main:app (1 packages loaded, 83 targets
> configured). INFO: Found 1 target... ERROR:
> C:/tmp/6jyys53n/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:13:25: Extracting
> interface @androidsdk//:dx_jar_import failed: missing input file
> 'external/androidsdk/build-tools/33.0.0/lib/dx.jar', owner:
> '@androidsdk//:build-tools/33.0.0/lib/dx.jar' ERROR:
> C:/tmp/6jyys53n/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:13:25: Extracting
> interface @androidsdk//:dx_jar_import failed: 1 input file(s) do not
> exist Target //src/main:app failed to build ERROR:
> C:/tmp/6jyys53n/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:13:25 Extracting
> interface @androidsdk//:dx_jar_import failed: 1 input file(s) do not
> exist INFO: Elapsed time: 0.921s, Critical Path: 0.07s INFO: 7
> processes: 7 internal. FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

Here are some environment variables/files I have set according to installation instructions:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=C:\Users\scott\OneDrive\Desktop\android-ndk-r25
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16
PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\bazelisk\downloads\bazelbuild\bazel-5.2.0-windows-x86_64\bin
WORKSPACE=C:\Users\scott\examples\android\tutorial

C:\ProgramData\bazel.bazelrc:
    startup --output_user_root=C:/tmp
    startup --windows_enable_symlinks
    build --enable_runfiles
```

I have Android API 33 downloaded through Android studio, machine running Windows 11.

Any suggestions on how to address this? I'm new to Bazel and haven't built anything before with it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Upgrade your bazel and build with this version as mentioed here https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/13989#issuecomment-1170560215. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Original problem fixed, now getting another error in building - see edits to original post.

Comment: Have you tried implementing [Desugaring](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/desugaring-in-android/) as shown here.

Comment: Hi there - I've also noticed this problem (desugaring failure on Windows) recently. Try removing `--enable_runfiles` from your build flags and see if that helps.

Comment: That worked to remove enable_runfiles! Thanks a bunch! Bazel's Windows specific instructions recommend including this...maybe that needs to be edited? https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/windows.html#best-practices

Comment: I think this issue is specific just to the Android desugaring actions in the Bazel build on Windows, so disabling this feature for all Bazel + Windows would not be the best course of action. I'll try to craft a fix for this.