# Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file

Tags: android, bazel

I'm getting an error during building Test DPC app for Android. Downloaded this directly from GitHub, and haven't successfully built it before. I have multidex enabled but it still appears that it's trying to put the output into one file. Details are below.

> C:\Users\scott\OneDrive\Desktop\test_dpc\android-testdpc-testing_password>bazel
> build --noincremental_dexing testdpc
>
> Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it... INFO: Analyzed
> target //:testdpc (59 packages loaded, 1462 targets configured). INFO:
> Found 1 target... INFO: From Merging manifest for //:testdpc_lib:
> Warning:
> C:\tmp\u3afdanh\execroot_*main*_\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:208:9-211:35
> Warning:
> provider#androidx.startup.InitializationProvider was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:208 to remove other declarations but no other
> declaration present INFO: From Merging compiled Android resources for
> //:testdpc_lib: Warning:
> C:\tmp\u3afdanh\execroot_*main*_\bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin_renamed\testdpc_lib\AndroidManifest.xml:218:9-221:35
> Warning:
> provider#androidx.startup.InitializationProvider was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:218 to remove other declarations but no other
> declaration present ERROR:
> C:/users/scott/onedrive/desktop/test_dpc/android-testdpc-testing_password/BUILD:73:15:
> Converting bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/testdpc_deploy.jar to
> dex format failed: (Exit 1): d8_compat_dx.exe failed: error executing
> command (from target //:testdpc)
> bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\androidsdk\d8_compat_dx.exe
> --dex --force-jumbo --multi-dex --output=bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/_dx/testdpc/intermediate_classes.dex.zip
> ... (remaining 1 argument skipped) Error: Cannot fit requested classes
> in a single dex file (# methods: 91781 > 65536 ; # fields: 69326 >
> 65536). Try supplying a main-dex list Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.AssertionError: Failure
> at com.google.devtools.build.android.r8.CompatDx.main(CompatDx.java:478)
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException:
> Compilation failed to complete, position: null
> at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.3.28.java:0)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:75)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:28)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:27)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.b(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:2)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:6)
> at com.google.devtools.build.android.r8.CompatDx.run(CompatDx.java:624)
> at com.google.devtools.build.android.r8.CompatDx.main(CompatDx.java:472)
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: Cannot fit requested
> classes in a single dex file (# methods: 91781 > 65536 ; # fields:
> 69326 > 65536)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.DT.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:14)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.DT.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:22)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.h30.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:524)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.c30.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:7)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.F2.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:371)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.F2.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:455)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:756)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:24)
> ... 4 more Target //:testdpc failed to build Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps. INFO: Elapsed time: 329.684s, Critical Path: 179.76s INFO: 695
> processes: 40 internal, 579 local, 76 worker. FAILED: Build did NOT
> complete successfully

Here are some environment variables/files I have set:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=C:\Users\scott\OneDrive\Desktop\android-ndk-r25
BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2
Path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\bazelisk\downloads\bazelbuild\bazel-5.2.0-windows-x86_64\bin;
WORKSPACE=C:\Users\scott\OneDrive\Desktop\test_dpc\android-testdpc-testing_password

**C:\ProgramData\bazel.bazelrc**:
    startup --output_user_root=C:/tmp
    startup --windows_enable_symlinks


**BUILD file**:
  android_binary(
      name = "testdpc",
      custom_package = PACKAGE,
      dexopts = [
          "--force-jumbo",
      ],
      manifest = MANIFEST,
      multidex = "native",
      deps = [
          ":testdpc_lib",
      ],
  )

**WORKSPACE file**:
  maven_install(
    artifacts = [
       ...,
       "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1",
       ...
    ],...
  )

  android_sdk_repository(
      name = "androidsdk",
      api_level = 33,
      build_tools_version = "30.0.3"
  )
```

I have Android API 33 downloaded through Android studio, machine running Windows 11.

Any suggestions on how to address this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of bazel are you using? See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/15742 for details on this issue

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, I'll try the workarounds outlined in that thread. I'm using 6.0.0-pre.20220608.2

Comment: you might try using bazel version 6.0.0-pre.20220421.3 or earlier. the next pre-release (next week maybe?) should include the fix https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/ce55639c3ef2b9bd703d64026c40df0b7485b6a5

Comment: I was advised to upgrade to a more recent version to fix this bug here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73115972/bazel-android-hello-world-tutorial-error-building

Comment: Unfortunately, you're running into 3 separate but related issues: 1) using a build_tools_version that's too new for bazel -- this is solved by using 30.0.3 (this should be fixed in 6.0, or an upcoming rolling release) 2) D8 + multidex is unfortunately broken -- this is fixed in bazel at head 3) runfiles issues on windows -- this is workedaround with `--enable_runfiles=false` (or removing the flag). So try using 6.0.0-pre.20220421.3 (or 5.x assuming you don't need something in 6.0 pre-releases) with runfiles off